# Get Date after adding month and leave above days

Tags: php, javascript

```
$start_date = "2012-01-05";   
$end_date = "2012-02-10";
```

How to get month and after getting month date should like in above example

`$end_date` should "2012-02-05"; leave above 5 days. don't count a above day.

How can i do this in php?

I wan't to like

```
$month = 1;   
$end_date =   "2012-02-05";
```

Second Example

```
$start_date = "2012-06-19";  
$end_date = "2012-09-25";
```

then should

```
$month = 3;   
$end_date = "2012-09-19";
```

Leave days between "2012-09-19" to "2012-09-25".

Thanks

Comment: You should look up the date and datetime manipulation functions of whatever language you're in. Every good language has a way to construct dates from certain parameters like a year and month, and to increment month/decrement month/increment day/etc safely.

Comment: [this](http://www.phpjabbers.com/date-and-time-manipulations-with-php-php30.html) can help

Comment: You [agreed to do thorough research](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) before asking questions, but your question shows not such effort. Which of the many existing questions about [handling dates have you checked](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=adding+month+date+php)? Why didnt they help solve your problem?

Comment: Here is what you want ... http://eval.in/11521

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$start = '2012-01-23';
$months = 12;
$date=new DateTime($start);
$date->modify('+'.$months.' month');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Thank you very much diplex19. Yes i wan't this type of answer. Thank you again....

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtotime()` to just add a number of months to your original date...

```
$start = '2012-01-23';
$months = 3;
$timeExpr = sprintf('+%d months', $months);
$end = date($start, strtotime($timeExpr));

echo $end; //will output '2012-04-23'
```